# Impossible to create a service instance in the code behind in Blazor server with DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side

It's strange because to me it's correct, am I missed something ?

With .NET 6, in `Program.cs` (single file)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
    builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    
    builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
    
    AddBlazorise(builder.Services);
    
    // Use Autofac
    builder.Host.UseAutoFac((context, builder) => builder.RegisterModule(new PresentationAutofacModule()));
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.MapBlazorHub();
    app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    app.Run();
    
    void AddBlazorise(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddBlazorise();
        services.AddBootstrap5Providers().AddFontAwesomeIcons();

}
```

---

In PresentationAutofacModule.cs

```
    using Autofac;
    using Module = Autofac.Module;
    public class PresentationAutofacModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            var presentationAssembly = typeof(PresentationAutofacModule).Assembly;
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(presentationAssembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }
    }
```

### In the code behind

```
public partial class Customers
{
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService; 
    
    [Inject]
    public ICustomerViewModel CustomersModel { get; set; }

    public Customers(ICustomerService customerService)
    {
        _customerService = customerService;
    }

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CustomersModel.Customers.Add(new CustomerModel("A", "B", "Re1"));
        CustomersModel.Customers.Add(new CustomerModel("C", "D", "Ref2"));
        CustomersModel.Customers.Add(new CustomerModel("E", "F", "Ref3"));
        
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Error :
System.MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'MyApplication.Pages.Customers'. Reason: No parameterless constructor.

Comment: Can you please share full [mre]?

Comment: @GuruStron ouch ... It's a big project, not so easy. I have to give the project (after removing a lot) or "just" the full program.cs and the full .razor.cs ?

Comment: Just create a new small one. It is not clear what `Customers`. If it is a blazor component - use `[Inject]`

Comment: For example - `[Inject] protected  ICustomerService CustomerService { get; set; }`

Comment: What does the constructor of your CustomerService look like? Does it take any arguments, other than other injected services? Because then the DI Container can't construct it.

Comment: _"I updated my code"_ - And completely changed the question. Is there still a problem now?  I can't tell.

Comment: And always include full error messages.

Comment: @HH It's still the failing code but I copy all the code not a part of the code

Comment: So what do you think "No parameterless constructor" means?  You don't need any constructor in a component.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
[Inject]
protected ICustomerService CustomerService { get; set; }
```

See [ASP.NET Core Blazor dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Close, but it has to be a property. `... CustomerService { get; set; }`

Comment: yes, you're correct. its just a typo

Comment: For following best practices, remove the `_` and start with a `C`